# iphone UIWebView store the current scroll position?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

i want to store the current scroll position of a webView and when i launch the application again . i want to restore that scroll position again ..

How to do that ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UIWebView is not a subclass of UIScrollView so you can't do it the "normal" way.

Looks like this javascript solution will do what you need: http://shortdivision.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/going-back-to-the-last-place-you-were-in-a-uiwebview/

Answer (score 5):

Since iOS5 [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scrollView) has `scrollView` property. You can use variable of type `CGPoint` defined like this:

```
CGPoint _scrollPosition;
```

Then initialize it:

```
_scrollPosition = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

Whereever you need to store the current position use:

```
_scrollPosition = _webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
```

Implement `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and add code to restore the position inside `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // .... your other code here ...

    if (0 < _scrollPosition.y) {
        _webView.scrollView.contentOffset = _scrollPosition;
        _scrollPosition = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    }
}
```